# What if kafka have one node(broker) cluster and its down. client send messages to kafka producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

My client keep on sending message to kafka producer to produce message.

But I have one kafka broker in my kafka cluster. that broker is down for some time.
In that case my client message will be lost for that time. how to recover those messages.

And is there any solution for this. Even I have multiple broker also in my cluster there might be chance all the broker are disconnected from client.

Comment: You should set your [producer acks](https://kafka.apache.org/22/generated/producer_config.html#:~:text=acks,from%20the%20server%20at%20all.) to at least 1 to wait for the lead broker to acknowledge receipt of the message. It might still get lost of that broker fails after doing this and before storing the message so you might want to use more brokers and a higher ack count. This cannot remove the risk completely but reduce it by a lot.